# OraHome92Agent won't start

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have an Oracle9i installation on a virtual machine. The machine is a copy of a physical server that has beeen shutdown.

The machine has 2 discs that are mapped to drives C and E. C contains the OraHome and E apppers to have the data files.

All other Oracle services can start. Except for the OraHome92Agent that terminates.

What can I do to get the agent running?

I'm a very casual Oracle user that knows how to tnsping and sqlplus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OraHome92Agent must be an Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) related service. 
Your database should be fine without this service.

This service is not starting as You have this whole thing as copy of another machine. Agent still have configuration details from original machine, which restrict it to start.

If you really want to use OEM & remove this dB from OEM & discover this database instance again in OEM

As I said, your dB should be fine without it.

Regards, 
Abhi

Comment: I did some more fiddling and made sure that the E drive was changed to D.

The DB runs just fine without the Agent.  Thanks for clarifying that :-)